# Microphone issue - Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa

Tags: linux-mint, audio, microphone

I have a serious issue with the microphone on my laptop (running Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa) :

- I cannot record from a headset plugged in the jack port
- I have a poor record quality (very noisy in the background) when I use : USB-C mic, laptop mic or USB-C earplug.

My config :

Acer Swift 3 - SF314-42 Linux Mint 20.1 Cinnamon Cinnamon 4.8.6 5.8.0-44-generic x86_64 AMD ryzen 7 - 4700U with Radeon Graphics AMD Renoir driver N/A 16 GB

Answer (score 0):

The 'pavucontrol' has more control capabilities, check it out:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Comment: That is done already ;)